# How to sign & timestamp log or zip files?

Tags: digital-signature, timestamp

I think I can easily sign the files however I also need a timestamp from 3rd party vendor. I want to digitally sign + stamp log files including DHCP & mail because of laws here.

UPDATE: I found more info about time stamping. 
http://www.signfiles.com/timestamping/

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are asking, it seems to me you are looking for a File Integrity Monitoring solution. Are you familiar with FIMs, or have you researched them? Do you think that fits what you are looking for?

Not sure what budget you are working with, but [Tripwire](http://www.tripwire.com/it-security-software/security-configuration-management/file-integrity-monitoring/) is popular FIM vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Please see other answers on this site that provide resources on secure timestamping:

- [On-line cryptographically signed date/time?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/9491/971)
- [Signature and Timestamp for Long Term Document Archival Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17439/971)
- [Whic one is a good service of timestamp? [closed]](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11375/971)
- [Geographic equivilent of RFC 3161 (X.509 PKI Time-stamp Protocol)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6002/971)

and on Crypto.SE:

- [How are timestamps verified?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1816/351)
- [Is there an algorithm or hardware that can sign/verify natural time?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/932/351)

They should cover this topic in great detail.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Open Timestamps](https://opentimestamps.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Signing and timestamping ZIP archives can be tricky, so if this is what you're planning to do I would suggest you to look into the [ASiC standard (ETSI TS 102 918)](http://webapp.etsi.org/ewp/copy_file.asp?wki_id=42455).

Note that signing / timestamping a ZIP file may not have the same legal value as signing / timestamping individual files from the ZIP archive (better check your local jurisprudence first).